# how IProgressMonitor pause?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, progress-bar

How I can add an pause button to IProgressMonitor at an eclipse view. I have found only the chancel button. It works correctly, but I have to do an pause operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not available via the [interface](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html). The only thing that can be done is to setCancel() and even that does not 100% guarantee that the task it is performing will be cancelled. The tasks can be cancelled only if the actual job supports/and can perform cancelling.

Also what exactly would a "pause" semantically mean? Do you want to lock resources and wait? For how long? Things like these would have been arguments against having the method, I *think*.